# How to say it correctly? "I was sailing [..]" or "I sailed [..]"

Tags: past-tense, past-continuous

How to say the following correctly?

- Last Voyage I was sailing on board of container ship

or

- Last voyage I sailed on board of the container ship

and please explain why is your option right.

For example, you give interview and you are asked following question:

- What type of ship did you sail on last voyage?

Comment: You need to provide more context about where you read this or where you are writing this. Also before asking us, do provide your own opinion and explanation of why you think one is correct over another.

Comment: Dhanishtha Ghosh 

I'm not native speaker, i just don't know how to say correctly. For example I sit on interview and employer ask me "What type of ship were you in your last voyage?"

Comment: Use Past Continuous *(I was sailing)* if your text goes on to say something about *what happened during the voyage*. Otherwise (particularly if what you talk about next relates to *after arriving at your destination*) use Simple Past *(I sailed)*.

Comment: @Ivan You could have added that in your question to provide more insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Last voyage I sailed on board **a** container ship."

or a more complete:

"On my last voyage I sailed on board a container ship."

or a more complete and specific:

"On my last voyage I sailed on board the container ship _______"